# Manipulate is not plotting

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the output function of omega with the rest of the variables as parameters. I tried but its not plotting due t some reason. I tried removing omega m from the function and manipulate, then the plot came but it was blank. Can someone clarify what I am doing wrong?

[image]

EDIT: When I use a non-scripted variable. The plot does come but its blank. Can someone try to plot that function with manipulate?

Comment: Have you tried avoiding Subscript?

Comment: Yes. Now it did plot when I change the subscript variable. But now its showing a blank plot.

Comment: Post the code then we can test it.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, people who wan to help you will have do a lot of work to reproduce your problem so they can experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: Sure I apologize for this. What can I now do with this? Should I delete this? Or vote to close?

Comment: Also in what form and how to pasre the code? I have an equation as well and when I paste it in mathML some latin symbols get missed.